# Why does this Android application immediately crash?

Tags: android, crash

I leave you the code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.disposizione);
    Button pulsante = new Button(this);
    pulsante.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    pulsante.setText("Click me");
    pulsante.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Thug life bitch!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    layout.addView(pulsante);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

I tried to remove all the lines from the RelativeLayout to the layout.addView one and so it works again!

What's wrong in this code? I must say that I don't get any build error or warnings.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

write `setContentView()` immediate after `super.onCreate()`

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Comment: OMG I didn't know they had to be in sequence. I've learned one more thing and you made my day. I'm having a shower and then I'll set this as the correct answer. I just love you!